# Hard drive SMART values - failure prediction

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

I recently went through my pile of computer components (dusty garbage) and found that I got a lot of 5~7 years old sata drives lying around.

I found a couple of 400gb sata drives are from around 2007 - and they got an average Power-On Time of around 7 months.

**Question** Which SMART values from a the drive diagnostics table are the most important to predict an hardware failure?

Can't find any data on what's the industry average before a drive gets an hardware failure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The most important and really the only statistic I worry about how many reallocated sectors exist.  Simply stated this number indicates how many sectors had to be moved because an existing sector was determined to be bad by the firmware.

Comment: Thanks, so it seems that does relocations typically start to happen before an major h/w failure, correct?

Comment: A working hdd typical has a very low amount of sectors it believes to be bad or none at all.  A failing drive will often detect a large amount of sectors, and this fact, will often lead to the hdd spending a large amount of time moving files off "bad sectors".  Most of the time this can result in your system crashing, files becoming corrupt, or your system feeling like its "slow"

Answer (score 0):

1. pending sectors
2. reallocated sectors
3. scan errors
4. offline reallactions

I can't explain 3. and 4. because I doubt that those actions take place in my desktop environment.

This is according to the famous google study
https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/de//archive/disk_failures.pdf

You supposed:

> Thanks, so it seems that does relocations typically start to happen before an major h/w failure, correct?

No. They write that 56% of drives fail without any previous sign of SMART parameter degradation. The remaining 44% is not something I would consider as "typical".

Consider this study as a rough indication because it may not be comparable to the use profile of your barely used old drives.
I would guess that your drive might be more prone to electronics failure.